# The first "staff only" door is locked - how to progress?

Tags: dead-rising

I used the staff only door at the starting area (down from helipad to the warehouse) to progress to the mall, now locked. I'm not aware of any alternative paths.

[image]

Comment: Is this the door at the end of the long thin hallway?  The hallway where you can typically find a pistol?

Comment: @Mumford451: No, the starting area. Next to janitor's room.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you able to get back to the roof?  Or is that what you are asking? (Sorry, Its been a while since the last time I played)

Comment: @Mumford451: Yes, I didn't notice the air duct behind me. Posted as an answer. You can go now ;)

Comment: Haha Roger That!  Happy Killing! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate path, right across from the locked door:

[image]